# Efficiently generating the set of all words of length n from an alphabet in Julia

Tags: arrays, optimization, julia

*While similar questions have already been posted on this website, none of them deal with the Julia language. I have already implemented a working version of the algorithm, and am looking for language-specific optimisations.*

Here is the code I've written in Julia:

```julia
S(a::Array, n::Int64)::Array{Array} = n == 0 ? [[]] : vcat([push!.(deepcopy(S(a, n-1)), α) for α in a]...)
```

Although this code works as intended, it is quite slow and consumes a lot of memory.

I've tried optimising it slightly by avoiding recomputing `S(a, n-1)` several times:

```julia
S(a::Array, n::Int64)::Array{Array} = n == 0 ? [[]] : (arr::Array{Array} -> vcat([push!.(deepcopy(arr), α) for α in a]...))(S(a, n-1))
```

The issue of memory ineffciency, however, persists. Is there any way in which I can optimise this code to make it more memory efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following does what you want.

```
using Base.Iterators
T(a,n) = product(repeated(a,n)...)
```

This is better in several ways. Firstly, it produces an iterator, so uses roughly no memory. Second, it is type stable, whereas the version you wrote produces arrays with eltype `Any`, which will make code that uses it type unstable.

Furthermore, it is much faster.

```
julia> @time S([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 6);
  1.767797 seconds (16.22 M allocations: 1.315 GiB, 20.28% gc time)

julia> @time T([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 6);
  0.000013 seconds (17 allocations: 576 bytes)

julia> @time collect(T([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 6));
  0.004837 seconds (20 allocations: 24.328 MiB)
```

Note that even when you collect the result to get the same answer (an array), it still is over 400x faster and allocates much less memory.

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially what I was looking for! The output is a multi-dimensional array, but I suppose that can be linearized using `reshape`?

Comment: yes. Technically `vec` might be even cleaner as it is basically a shorthand for reshaping to a 1d array.

Comment: Use `:` operator to drop the dimension so it is `collect(T([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3))[:]` or even better `view(collect(T([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3)),:)`